# Access Denied error while trying to use AWS CLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I have a user in AWS having Full admin access but still when I try to describe my EC2 instances or List S3 buckets, I get an Access denied error message - examples below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-2

An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to contact Amazon support as we can't diagnose anything from just an access denied message

Comment: @vikas-gupta Can you please let us know how it is resolved, me too get stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt or Linux shell type "aws configure". Verify that the credentials and default region are correct (the last four characters will be displayed). I had the same problem today and I forgot to configure my access keys on a new machine.

Comment: You can also run `aws iam get-user` to view the current user making the request